# Как сделать так что бы при нажатие правой кнопки мыши на поле text появлялось меню где есть копировать вставить

Tags: python, tkinter, меню

я новичок в Python.Не знаю как сделать что бы при нажатие в поле ввода правой кнопкой мыши появись пункты копировать вставить.Я даже сейчас просто скопировать вставить обычным сочетанием клавиш не могу.

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Тест")
root.geometry("500x350")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

text = Text(width=59, height=10, bg="#F8F8FF", fg='black', wrap=WORD).place(x=10, y=36)
text = Label(text="Поле ввода", font="20").place(x=90, y=6)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> как сделать что бы при нажатие в поле ввода правой кнопкой мыши
>   появись пункты копировать вставить

Реакция на нажатие клавиш (и их комбинаций) задаётся с помощью метода *bind()*. По подробней - смотрите тут:

[ссылка](https://younglinux.info/tkinter/bind.php)

Ещё один совет - никогда (!) не пользуйтесь явным размещением виджетов в окне. Доверяйте это дело менеджерам компоновки TkInter.

С учётом этих двух замечаний, Ваша программа выглядит как-то так:

```
from tkinter import *

def copy_fun(event):
    print("Копирование")

def paste_fun(event):
    print("Вставка")

root = Tk()

root.title("Тест")
root.geometry("500x350")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

t1 = Text(width=59, height=10, bg="#F8F8FF", fg='black', wrap=WORD)
lbl = Label(text="Поле ввода", font="20")
t1.bind('<Control-C>', copy_fun)
t1.bind('<Control-V>', paste_fun)

lbl.pack()
t1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Я не стал рисовать контекстное меню, а просто показал, как задать реакцию на нажатие Control-C и Control-V. Обратите внимание на регистр (!!!) букв C и V  при нажатии в комбинации с Control

Если же главной проблемой является создание контекстного меню, то можно как-то так:

```
from tkinter import *

def copy_fun():
    print("Копирование")

def paste_fun():
    print("Вставка")

mn = Menu(tearoff=0)
mn.add_command(label="Copy", command=copy_fun)
mn.add_command(label="Paste", command=paste_fun)

x = 0
y = 0

def popup(event):
    global x, y
    x = event.x
    y = event.y
    mn.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)

root = Tk()

root.title("Тест")
root.geometry("500x350")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

t1 = Text(root, width=59, height=10, bg="#F8F8FF", fg='black', wrap=WORD)
lbl = Label(root, text="Поле ввода", font="20")
t1.bind('<Button-3>', popup)

lbl.pack()
t1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: А разве Text сам не поддерживает Ctrl+C и Ctrl+V (с tk не работал)? В вопросе ведь говорилось про меню, что должно появиться при клике по правой кнопке, а не про само действие копирования и вставки. Мб автор захочет еще действий, помимо копирования, в него добавить...

Comment: @gil9red *разве Text сам не поддерживает Ctrl+C и Ctrl+V ?* - разумеется, поддерживает. Но ведь TS хочет не этого, а по нажатию этих комбинаций выполнить  некое ДЕЙСТВИЕ. Конкретно - нарисовать меню. Вот я и показал, как запустить произвольную функцию, выполняющую любые действия, по нажатию некоей комбинации клавиш.

Comment: Но автор хочет показать меню при клике по правой кнопке: `как сделать что бы при нажатие в поле ввода правой кнопкой мыши появись пункты копировать вставить`

Comment: по моему глобальные `x,y` тут вообще не к чему они не используются. + ваш код зачем то создает новое окно специально для `mn = Menu(tearoff=0)` т.к. вы его вынесли до токо как объявили функцию `Tk` )

Comment: так же уж можно было добавить вместо принтов само действия. простые 2 функции `t1.event_generate('<Control-c>')` и `t1.event_generate('<Control-v>')`

Comment: Как сделать так что при нажатии ctr c ctrl v не приходилось каждый раз менять регистр?

Comment: @Leon *Как сделать* - да просто напишите по два вызова *bind* - на маленькую букву и на большую.

Comment: Прошу прощения я неправильно задал вопрос.Как сделать что-бы мне при нажатии ctrl c и crtl v не приходилось каждый раз переключать на английский язык.Если язык включён русский то эти команды не работают,и ещё каким образом сделать что-бы копирование и вставка работала с буфером обмена компьютера?

Comment: @Leon *"не приходилось каждый раз переключать на английский язык"* - я думаю, что если Вы хотите получить одну реакцию на 4 (!) разных клавиатурных комбинаций, то и нужно четыре бинда. Для: Ctrl/v, Ctrl/V, Ctrl/м и Ctrl/М.

Comment: @Leon *"что-бы копирование и вставка работала с буфером обмена компьютера?"* - В пакете tkinter есть функции *clipboard_get(self, **kw), clipboard_clear(self, **kw) и clipboard_append(self, string, **kw).*  Но с каким именно буфером они работают я, честно говоря, не знаю.

Проверил - нормально работает!